# How to prevent reloading in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two pages let's say page A and page B, page A can link to page B, and page B has a Return button can go back to page A. Inside page A, there is a paginated table which is a child component. each time when I click on the Return button on page B, it triggers this.porps.history.goBack() function and takes me to page A. and the problem is here, each time when I go back from page B to page A, the page A will be reloaded and the paginated table will be reloaded as well which means I will always see the first page content of the table no matter which page I was in of the table before.

I am wondering if there is way to solve this problem? Let's say in page A the table is showing second page content, when I go to page B and click Return button back to page A, in page A the table is showing second page content instead of the first page content.

Comment: not sure if this would help, but have you tried preventDefault? Or just set the data that you want into state so no matter what page you go to and come back you can load the correct page's data and then also clear state when you need to

Comment: @mastercool I tried preventDefault, but it doesn't work.

Comment: how is the table being rendered? is it being rendered using values in State?

Comment: @mastercool the table is from ant Design. and the pagination is a built-in function from the table I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways I can think of now.

1. Your url can store your page number. /page-a?page=2
   Based on query param (2 in this case), you can render the proper page
2. Page B can just be populated on top of page A.

```
   <PageA>
      PageAContent
      <Route path="/page-b">
         <PageB>
            PageBContent
         </PageB>
      </Route>
   <PageB>
```

This way you can just keep the content of PageA without refreshing it.

Comment: I am using the table from ant Design, and the pagination function is a built-in function. the table is only one part of the page A's content, so the url doesn't show the page number like /page-a?page=2.

Comment: if the table is only one part of the page A's content, url solution might not be the best one.
Please try the second solution posted

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand why if you populate page B on the top of page A, when you click the return button on page B it  takes you to page A and page A on't be reloaded?

Comment: In that case, it is not switching route but just cancelling inner route.
I thought you would have url system something like
"/page-a/page-b"
If that's not the case, I agree it won't work.

Comment: It is not the case. Thank you though!